# CORS errors in PHP backend consumed by Reactjs

Tags: php, reactjs, cors

When I make a POST request I get the error 
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/vla-php/room/create.php' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.` 
on the console.

Using Postman works fine, however, trying to consume it from a React frontend results in the above error.

I already have CORS enabled by setting access control to allow all origins (*)

`.htaccess` is an empty file. I doubt if that would be a hinderance.

The PHP code looks like so;

```
<?php
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

// get database connection
include_once '../config/database.php';

// instantiate product object
include_once '../objects/room.php';

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

$room = new Room($db);

// get posted data
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

// make sure data is not empty
if(
    !empty($data->name) &&
    !empty($data->category) &&
    !empty($data->type)
){

    // set product property values
    $room->name = $data->name;
    $room->category = $data->category;
    $room->type = $data->type;

    // create the product

    if($room->create()){

        // set response code - 201 created
        http_response_code(201);

        // tell the user
        echo json_encode(array("message" => "Room was created."));
    }

    // if unable to create the product, tell the user
    else{

        // set response code - 503 service unavailable
        http_response_code(503);

        // tell the user
        echo json_encode(array("message" => "Unable to create room."));
    }
}

// tell the user data is incomplete
else{

    // set response code - 400 bad request
    http_response_code(400);

    // tell the user
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Unable to create room. Data is incomplete."));
}
?>
```

Comment: Does your backend properly respond to [preflight requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests)?

Answer (score -1):

Changing the headers to

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization");
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if ($method == "OPTIONS") {
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization");
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
die();
}
```

Worked